# Offline file transfer into Android-x86 virtual machine?

Tags: internal-storage, android-x86, virtualbox

VirtualBox SMB servers are unfortunately unsupported by Android and it's third party file managers.

How do I transfer files into an Android VM without needing to upload the file online (if no Internet connection is available)?

Comment: VM softwares should already offer a function called "shared folders".

Comment: @AndyYan As already said, that one does not quite work. Some networks show up in ES File Manager, but they require passwords.